# Is it possible to use AssistedInject to inject members other than in the constructor?

Tags: java, guice

I want to do something like this:

```
@Inject private CollectorsListHolderFactory collectorsListHolderFactory;
private CollectorsListHolder collectorsListHolder;
private String projectName;
private NodeInfo node;

@Inject
public CollectorsRunner(@Assisted String projectName, @Assisted NodeInfo node) {
    super();
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.node = node;
    collectorsListHolder = collectorsListHolderFactory.create(projectName, node);
}
```

but I get `NullPointerException` because `collectorsListHolderFactory` is `null`. is it possible to inject that member without using the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assisted inject is happy to inject fields, same as the rest of Guice, but it happens *after* the constructor is called.  (After all, it needs to create the instance before it can set its fields.)  You can do this:

```
private final String projectName;
private final NodeInfo node;
private CollectorsListHolder collectorsListHolder;

@Inject
public CollectorsRunner(@Assisted String projectName, @Assisted NodeInfo node) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.node = node;
}

@Inject
void injectCollectorsListHolderFactory(CollectorsListHolderFactory factory) {
    this.collectorsListHolder = factory.create(projectName, node);
}
```

But if you can, you should [avoid public injectable constructors](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/KeepConstructorsHidden) entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

```
private CollectorsListHolder collectorsListHolder;
private String projectName;
private NodeInfo node;

@Inject
public CollectorsRunner(@Assisted String projectName, @Assisted NodeInfo node,
                       CollectorsListHolderFactory collectorsListHolderFactory) {
    super();
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.node = node;
    this.collectorsListHolder = collectorsListHolder;
}
```

You must bind the collectorsListHolder in your module in order that to work btw.

Comment: This is working for me. I wanted to inject directly to the field member because I have many field members later on.

Comment: Then don't use assisted inject at all. And remove the     @Inject annotation from the constructor.

Comment: My reply was probably confusing. some of the injection need to be assisted (and for that I didn't saw examples without the constuctor). The rest of the members I want to inject directly and not using the constructor. If it was possible I'd prefer also use the '@Assisted' annotation on the members directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a JSR-250 extension for guice, like [mycila](https://github.com/mycila/guice) or other, and use the @PostConstruct annotation.